# java server socket

Tags: java, serversocket

i wanted to create a java server and client in a same file...because this is my structure of project

SERVER ---> CLIENT/SERVER ----> CLIENT

the coding for the SERVER and CLIENT part is quite simple but i have a problem when creating for CLIENT/SERVER part.. where my code can only run CLIENT part and not starting the SERVER part. because of my thread run() code.

```
package com.main.datadistributor;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;

    public class Slave {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Config cfg = new Config("Slave");
        String MasterServerIP = cfg.getProperty("MasterServerIP");
        String MasterServerPort = cfg.getProperty("MasterServerPort");
        String SlaveServerPort = cfg.getProperty("SlaveServerPort");

        Client client = new Client(MasterServerIP,Integer.parseInt(MasterServerPort),"SLAVEONE");
        client.run();

        int numClient = 0;
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(SlaveServerPort));
        System.out.println("Server starts running");

        try{
            while(true){
                new Server(listener.accept(), numClient++, Integer.parseInt(SlaveServerPort), "SLAVESERVER").start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }


    }
}
```

from the code above i have problem only executing client.run() and the code just stop there without proceeding to execute new Server below at the try section

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: What is client.run(); ? Why not a thread for this thing too ?

Answer (score 2):

If `Client` subclasses `Thread`, then you need to call `start()`, not `run()`.  If it implements `Runnable` then you need to instantiate a `Thread` to execute it and call the thread's `start()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what `Client` is, or seeing its code limits our ability to help.  If it has a `run()` method it may implement `Runnable`, so you can possibly just call `new Thread(client).start()` instead of calling its run method directly.